# NSArray third party subclass to hold primitive value

Tags: cocoa, collections, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsset

**Update:** With new additions (subscripting and numerals), this question is out-of date.

---

I have seen recently some code for a class subclassing `NSArray` (or any collection class) to hold primitive values.

The idea was instead of writing:

```
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:42]];
[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

you could write:

```
myArray = [NSPrimitiveObjectArray arrayWithObject:42];
[myArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

I can't find this code anymore. Would someone have seen it as well, and remember the url?

I would also appreciate feedback from people who have used it -or similar code- and what they think about it. The reason I didn't save the link when seeing this code was that I got a feeling of hacking with the language that might bring problems in the long term.

Comment: do you need this for every primitive type ? or you could just write your category ?

Comment: @Vince I could just write the category. But since I know it exists, it has no real value. I also am not sure it will be really useful in the long term. There might be more gotchas than benefits, and some feedback from people who have done so might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were doing this, I'd probably just write a category on NSArray and/or NSMutableArray. Something like this:

```
@interface NSMutableArray (PrimitiveAccessors)

- (void)addInteger:(NSInteger)value;
- (NSInteger)integerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)addFloat:(float)value;
- (float)floatAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

// etc...

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (PrimitiveAccessors)

- (void)addInteger:(NSInteger)value;
{
    [self addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]];
}

- (NSInteger)integerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
{
    id obj = [self objectAtIndex:index];
    if (![obj respondsToSelector:@selector(integerValue)]) return 0;
    return [obj integerValue];
}

- (void)addFloat:(float)value;
{
    [self addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:value]];
}

- (float)floatAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
{
    id obj = [self objectAtIndex:index];
    if (![obj respondsToSelector:@selector(floatValue)]) return 0;
    return [obj floatValue];
}

// etc...

@end
```

Really though, it sort of seems like more work than it's worth. Wrapping primitives in NSNumber and pulling them back out just isn't that hard...

Comment: Agreed, wrapping primitives is not hard, but it can be really frustrating. I love the verbosity of Objective-C because most of the time it makes the code really readable, but in this case, it just doesn't add any value.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. I also love that Objective-C is a superset of C, but this is one of those places where the boundary between the two causes some annoyance. If only int, float, etc were objects...